# How to dynamically add Components to a Blazor Server application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

We have a WinForms application where Controls are dynamically created based on customer-specific configurations. In WinForms it is very easy to add Controls and to set their event listeners at runtime, e.g. for a button we use code like this:

```
// Loop over custom dialog elements
[...]
Control c;
switch (type)
{
    case ElementType.Button:
        Button btn = new Button
        {
            Left = this.LeftValue,
            Top = this.TopValue,
            Width = this.Width,
            Height = this.Height,
            Text = this.Label
        };                        
        btn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
        c = btn;
        break;
        
        [...]
}
panel.Controls.Add(c);
```

We want to do the same for a web application, if possible using Blazor Server. Is this possible without too many work arounds or should we rather use a meta-approach, where application 1 creates code (e.g. razor and cs code) for application 2 based on the customer configuration and afterwards application 2 is compiled and then provided to the customer?

Comment: Anything is doable, the platform doesn't matter.   The complexity escalates as you add control types.  How do you handle all the usual stuff you need in edit forms.  Validation, exiting on dirty state,...   I don't thinks it's "very easy" on any platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can Do By
[Blazor Dynamic Components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/dynamiccomponent?view=aspnetcore-7.0)